# Local variables don't work in Razor helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This code does work inside Razor Views but does NOT work inside custom helpers body and in _Layout.cshtml:

```
@{ var v = "foo"; }
@v
```

Error message: "Element v does not exist in current context"

I use just downloaded Visual Web Developer Express 2010.

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code works fine in both views and `_layout.cshtml`. And as far as helpers are concerned here's the syntax:

```
@helper MyHelper()
{
    var v = "foo";
    @v    
}
@MyHelper()
```

This being said declaring local variables and writing C# code in views should be avoided.